# JQuery loop through array does not return the right value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have input form where I have error text in the array and I loop through it to assign input a error text fields, but my issue is that if the error for example on the last input it displays the first array option value not the last as should be. code below: have no access to the html.

If for example first fiel whats your name filled and there i no error message than the  "What's your name?" is displayed on where do you work input and not the "Who do you work for?" errro message, if all inputs are empty it works fine

```
var arr = [ "What's your name?", "Who do you work for?", "Most convenient 
phone number to call you on:", "Best email address to contact you on:", 
"Tell us what you'd like to know about:"];

    // setting the interval to check that the elements displayed as needed
    var timer = setInterval(function () {
        for (var i=0, l=arr.length; i<l; i++) {             
            // i believe the below line has the issue  
            (jQuery('.validation_message:eq('+[i]+')').text(arr[i])); 

        }    
    }, 500)
```

Comment: Can you post a working example using the snippet tool? (Ctrl+M)

Comment: also please share the html

Comment: I do not have html access

Comment: Remove the square brackets from i in the :eq part of the selector.

Comment: How about you try a couple of complete sentences?

Comment: that does not help

Comment: It does return the right value, it's just that your logic is wrong because every 500ms you're looping through the entire list again

Comment: I think you need something like `jQuery('.validation_message').each( function() { jQuery(this).text( arr[ jQuery(this).index() ]  ) });` (Or you need to get the index of the element by selecting its siblings) but it's very hard to help without seeing your html

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code as presented: https://jsfiddle.net/y8nwnabk/

Comment: thanks all for help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry was my mistake from my side, when selecting by eq(), if the the error does not appear the div is not created, so what I did added the parent div id than it all worked code below:

```
            jQuery('.gfield_contains_required').each(function(idx) {
            jQuery(this).attr('id', 'a' + idx);
            });

            (jQuery('#a' + i + ' .validation_message').text(arr[i]));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you feel the issue is (probably) with that line, how about taking a reference to the jQuery dom object targeting  `.validation_message` class and then use a `eq` function?

```
   var timer = setInterval(function () {
        var validationMsgDom = jQuery('.validation_message');
        for (var i=0, l=arr.length; i<l; i++) {             
            validationMsgDom.eq(i).text(arr[i]); 
        }    
   }, 500)
```